# How can a technically homeless German citizen issue an invitation for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, invitation-letters, schengen-visas

My friend has a problem to send *Verpflichtungserklärung* (VPE) to me. It seems the immigration office of her town wants more than only blocking 5000 Euros. They want her to prove she has a home. She is staying at her friend now and her lease for new flat is for July. But my interview for visa is on late June. They said she must be registered at the municipal administration which cannot happen in two weeks. So I think I should ask her to write me an informal invitation letter to present it to the embassy.

The problem is we don't know how to write it. 
Please let me know if there is a way to get VPE with current situation and if its not possible how should we write invitation letter, a sample would help.

Comment: As said already in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69374/what-is-the-detailed-process-of-getting-schengen-visa-by-locking-money-for-verpf , having a home is mandatory. ... Without being properly registered somewhere, theoretically she is a derelict => VPE impossible, and invitation letter won't help much. ... But I wonder why she isn't registered in the first place. And unless I misunterstood what you mean, this doesn't take two weeks, not even two days.

Comment: Are you asking for a template invitation letter explaining what it should cover?

Comment: If their friend owns the place she is staying at she could just register there, even if only for a few weeks. Registration takes 10mins + waiting time during office hours.

Comment: In addition to mts states, some city administrations now require to see a rental contract / letter by the landlord / proof of owning the place in order to perform the registration. But I'm sure that there is some way to get this for an informal sub-rent (i.e., without a contract).

Comment: @DCTLib I think her contract is starting from July, and I want to be there at Augest . But my interview is on 26 June and I need VPE soon. Can she register with that lease?

Comment: @GayotFow I want the template of an informal invitation letter. Also I want to know should she explain the problem occurred in the process too, please see comment above too.

Comment: @mts I think her contract is starting from July, and I want to be there at Augest . But my interview is on 26 June and I need VPE soon. Can she register with that lease? – Jamais avenir 1 min ago   edit

Comment: @Jamaisavenir She can probably do that, but she won't be registered at the new place until then. What I mean is that whereever she is staying now, the kind-of-landlord (friend) of her at her *current place* may be able to give documentation that shows that she has currently a place to live, so that she can register under that address.

Comment: In short, a legally homeless person can't help you in any (legal) way to get into the country. She should sort out her own problems first (eg. being registered at some place is mandatory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with user "9ilsdx 9rvj 0lo" that your friend needs to get her paperwork in order.

- A *Verpflichtungserklärung* is not only an invitation letter. She agrees to pay all costs of the goverment related to your stay (and your removal, should you overstay). Because of her low income, she will have to put some money into a bond. If something goes seriously wrong, e.g. with medical problems which are not covered by your travel insurance, she might have to pay **much** more than the 5000 Euro bond.
- She will have to explain where you will live during your intended stay. That can be a leased apartment if she has one, but she doesn't have one *yet*.
- She might be legally required to register *her own* stay at her friend's flat if she has no other registered primary place of residence within Germany. Depending on that friend's lease contract, subleasing may require the permission of the landlord. It is unlikely that your friend's situation would be investigated if the "inaccuracy" lasts just for a few weeks, but she shouldn't put any false statements regarding her place of residence into official records.

Answer (score 6):

You've got something wrong there. It's unlikely it's required to be home owner in order to issue VPE because most people in Germany don't own homes/flats, they just rent them.

It seems your friend is not registered at her current place of living, which is mandatory, and she should do that immediately! It doesn't matter who is the owner of the place where you stay, if you live in Germany, you must register under the address you're currently staying. Therefore your problem will be solved as well.

Comment: There are exceptions to that rule for *people who have registered a primary place of residence* in Germany. They can live elsewhere for half a year before they have to register, §27 (2).