# Will I be granted the Schengen visa if an affidavit of financial support is written by a student working in Germany?

Tags: schengen-visas

I'm invited by my girlfriend in Germany and she is supporting me with everything. So I want to know if i will be granted the Schengen visa, if she is the one who write the affidavit for financial support?

Comment: Your biggest headache will be trying to convince the authorities the purpose of your trip is not to settle over there with your girlfriend.

Answer (score 5):

Having €700 a month will not qualify her for a affidavit (*Verpflichtungserklärung*), unless she has a couple of thousand on her desposit. It is required to have an income of at least ~1300€ (depends on local authorities. It's [1479€ in Konstanz](http://www.konstanz.de/rathaus/02168/02191/02192/02195/index.html?lang=de&download=NHzLpZeg7t,lnp6I0NTU042l2Z6ln1acy4Zn4Z2qZpnO2Yuq2Z6gpJCFfH5_fGym162epYbg2c_JjKbNoKSn6A--) and [1290€ in Lippstadt](http://www.lippstadt.de/soziales/integration/auslaender/verpflichtungserklaerung.php)). But 700€ monthly will not be enough.

However she can make an invitation without financial obligations. In this case it's you who must prove having enough money for the whole period of stay.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on her financial circumstances. Being a student does **not** disqualify her, but a typical student could not afford to pay for your support.

If you look at [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71031/how-can-a-technically-homeless-german-citizen-issue-an-invitation-for-a-schengen) and [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69374/what-is-the-detailed-process-of-getting-schengen-visa-by-locking-money-for-verpf), there is an example how the city administration wanted the sponsor to post a bond because her income seemed too low.

---

**Follow-up:** The Verpflichtungserklärung covers not just the *planned* cost of your stay but also the *unplanned* costs for German government agencies if you can't or won't return home on schedule. So the planned length of stay does not matter. €700 a month does not leave much disposable income.

Comment: She earns €700 per month and im going to stay with her for 45 days .She is going to pay the plane ticket and my hotel room . So will it be much relavant and will it exempt her from being a typical student ?

Comment: @leo They will want her to show her bank account statements and/or payment slips for the last few month, possibly her rent contract to verify the apartment is large enough and she can afford the place and her daily life and you on top of that.